# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Currently im working on a new Spring 4 + Thymeleaf + Security project without XML bean files. Somehow the localization property files are not loading and i cant find anything about them in the log files.

```
/**
 * Generates the i18n language loader.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name="messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    resource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    resource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    return resource;
}

/**
 * Generates the i18n language changer parameter.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

/**
 * Genereates the default i18n language.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
    return localeResolver;
}

/**
 * Generates the template resolver for thymeleaf.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;

}

/**
 * Generates the template engine for thymeleaf.
 *
 * @return
 */
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return engine;
}

/**
 * Generates the view resolver from Spring MVC with thymeleaf intergrated.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*"});
    viewResolver.setCache(false);
    return viewResolver;
}

/**
 * Add resources.
 *
 * @param registry
 */
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/assets/");
}

/**
 * Add interceptors.
 * 
 * @param registry 
 */
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

File names in the src/main/resources/ folder:

- messages.properties
- messages_en.properties
- messages_nl.properties

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Slash character "/" denoting the classpath root is missing in the basename pattern of your ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.

```
resource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
```

Comment: Already tried to do that but doenst work that why im asking this question :) im lost with possible bugs

Comment: Why one of the messages file has no locale? Does regular bundle work?

Comment: Why one of the messages file has no locale? - Just for testing purposes to check if that works...

The regular ResourceBundleMessageSource bean doesnt work aswell

Comment: How do you build the application? Are all resources included? Just to make sure - Do you work with a deployed .war file that includes all the bundles?

Comment: Yes everything is included, the weirdest thing is he doesnt fire the loadProperties() method etc. from the spring library

Answer (score 0):

Javabase Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Bean
       public MessageSource messageSource() {
             ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new
                    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
             messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
             messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10);
             return messageSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
              LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
              factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
              return factoryBean;
        }

        @Override
        public Validator getValidator() {
              return localValidatorFactoryBean();
        }
 }
```

XmLbase Config:

Note: You should add mvc namespaces already.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validatorFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
</bean>

<bean id="validatorFactoryBean"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

Note: If you're trying to load from "webapp" folder so there is no need to use "classpath:" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I neded up with the following configuration for my dev env:

application.properties:

```
spring.messages.basename=file:src/main/resources/messages
spring.messages.cache-duration=0
```

Java configuration:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.messages")
public MessageSourceProperties messageSourceProperties() {
    return new MessageSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = AbstractApplicationContext.MESSAGE_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME)
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource( MessageSourceProperties properties ) {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    if (StringUtils.hasText( properties.getBasename() )) {
        messageSource.setBasenames( StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray( StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace( properties.getBasename() ) ) );
    }
    if (properties.getEncoding() != null) {
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding( properties.getEncoding().name() );
    }
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale( properties.isFallbackToSystemLocale() );
    Duration cacheDuration = properties.getCacheDuration();
    if (cacheDuration != null) {
        messageSource.setCacheMillis( cacheDuration.toMillis() );
    }
    messageSource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat( properties.isAlwaysUseMessageFormat() );
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage( properties.isUseCodeAsDefaultMessage() );
    return messageSource;
}
```

**Exaplanation**:

`spring.messages.basename=file:src/main/resources/messages` => read files directly from source
`spring.messages.cache-duration=0` => disable caching for files to be reloaded. Default is -1 which means cache forever.

The `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` bean is a direct copy from spring's `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java` impl, but using `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` instead as message source.

Bean needs to have name `AbstractApplicationContext.MESSAGE_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME` to disable default auto-configuration.